# How to use doT template engine with express 4 in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, templates

Looks like there is no `register` method in express 4. I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object function (req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  } has no method 'register'
```

What is the right way to use doT engine in express 4?

Comment: Does express-dot-engine not do Express 4? I haven't tried it.

Comment: Yes express-dot-engine supports Express 4

Answer (score 0):

- You can follow the express way: http://expressjs.com/advanced/developing-template-engines.html
- Or you can manually render with dot on your routes: https://github.com/olado/doT/blob/master/examples/express/lib/app.js